# php imagepng with double fwrite

Tags: php, image, fwrite

This php code appends TWO lines to file:

```
$t = microtime();
$fn = $DOCUMENT_ROOT."/test.txt";
$f = fopen($fn, "a");
fwrite($f, "\n". $t);
fclose($f);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(1,1);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Example outputs to file with ONE browse:
0.43408600 1412017949
0.46703300 1412017949

I want code just appending ONE line with ONE browse.

(imagejpeg or imagegif faster than imagepng?)

```
// This is an javascript debug trick:
new Image().src = "http://d_o_m_a_i_n/debug.php?p=msg";
```

see [facebook sdk](http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/debug.js) endpoint

Answer (score 1):

`new Image().src` as used there would trigger a reload of the `debug.php` file, which I presume is the URL of your image generator. You're triggering a second load of the image, hence two lines.

Comment: I tested it without javascript, just type url to browser.Hmm, Firefox v32 reproduce this, but Chrome v37 not! Is this a Firefox bug?

Comment: and javascript code is in the another file, for example html5.js, NOT in debug.php